# How can I make a script to only extract one value from the entire form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner with html and js. I'm trying to make a website that takes the input from a form and then (in a different page) displays those values. The problem is that I want to stylize different values different (1st value on the left, 2nd on the right of the page for example). I assume the way I could do this, is extracting every value with a different script and stylizing it inside the script with inline. Any help would be appreciated :)
Edit: I'm using GET method for my form

Comment: Please update the question with what you have tried. What is the code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to get data from a form, you would need a server side scripting language like php, node.js, Django and the likes. These frameworks/languages would help parse such data and return such data in a new page or even in the same page.